# Restore Postgres Database on New Machine

Tags: postgresql, psql

Trying to restore a postgres database on a new Macbook Pro.  I recreated the database using `createdb dbname` then tried to restore the old database using `psql dbname < dbname_dump.bin` but ended up with a bunch of errors like `ERROR:  relation "comments" already exists` and `ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "comments_pkey"`. What's up?

Comment: Can you try dumping the database, recreating, verifying it's empty, and re-importing?  If it does it again then check the actual file you're importing and see if it has everything listed 2x

Comment: Hey Ali, this worked, thank you!  I ended up deleting the tables from the db and was able to restore correctly.  However, still not sure how those tables and schema were created, given that I recreated the db on a completely new machine...

Comment: Great to hear.  I'll make that an answer so if anyone else finds this thread and runs into the same issue, they'll see it.  Thanks.  Let us know if you have more questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try dumping the database, recreating, verifying it's empty, and re-importing? If it does it again then check the actual file you're importing and see if it has everything listed 2x.